# PC date and time incorrect

Tags: date-time

I have all my PS's connected to Domain(using windows server 2012r2).
In all my PC,date and time automatically changes even after manually setting up through BIOS as well as system settings.
In my PC,Time Zone is correct and country also correct.
I even changed router time settings,which were wrong earlier.Still date and time changes automatically.

Can anyone suggest working clue..

Comment: Your clients are most likely relying on the domain controller to synchronize the time.  Make sure your DC is configured correctly to synchronize with an external NTP server or other reliable time source.

Answer (score 0):

What heavyd posted is correct. Your PCs are likely referencing your domain controller for their time settings. I would recommend checking and resolving any issues your domain controller has with its own time settings, but if you want to make changes to this specific computer you can either:

1) Edit your registry to pull time from an outside source. (such as time.windows.com) The change you have to make in regedit is: HLMC\SYSTEM\Currentcontrolset\Services\W32time\Parameters - look for the REG_SZ entry named "Type" and change the value from NT5DS to NTP.

2) You can also change that same registry key to NoSync instead, and this will stop your computer from referencing any outside source and simply run with the time you specify.

A reboot will be required after making either change.

Comment: Hi,I have tried your first step.It was OK initially i.e. my PC is having NTP values by default..But one more thing to ponder.Out of 10 Pc's connected to domain,some PC are showing exact time and date and some are showing wrong.So how can Domain Controller settings be wrong?

Comment: After I restart the PC's,then time changes automatically.Date remains correct.